# Insert return value from dll method into HTML input

Tags: c#, browser, browser-extension

I need to create a button that will call a method on a dll that is installed on the client and insert the return value into a form on an Intranet web page. I started creating a plugin for IE, but Microsoft is no longer supporting IE and Edge currently has no support for plug-ins. I thought maybe a Chrome extension, but Google is phasing out NPAPI support. Other browsers are not an option. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: wcf remoting and signalr are out of the question?

Comment: @Nissim, I'm not sure how those would help as the dll is on the client, not the server. Could you expand on it a bit?

Comment: Maybe you should expand more on the 'I need to create a button' part. where does this button sits (server/client, winform/webpage?)

Comment: @Nissim, in a browser toolbar plugin, or some other place that is readily accessible while viewing web pages.

Comment: You can't simply call a dll on another machine, it has to be loaded, you might want to think towards installing a simple web-service that will load the dll and listen for incoming requests in order to process your request and give you the desired return value (easy as pie if you use wcf). The next part - updating a web form - you can either use a timer to read the value from a shared resource every predefined time, or signalr if you want 'real-time' update

Comment: @Nissim, I didn't say the dll was on another machine. It's on the same client machine as the browser. I think my question maybe was confusing. I updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to create a "Native messaging host" console app that makes the call to the dll method. Then I made a Chrome extension that uses [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) to communicate with the console app.

Supposedly, once Microsoft Edge supports extensions, it will be able to use extensions that were made for Chrome and Firefox too.